# How to make blobstore delete operations transaction safe with ndb?

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore, app-engine-ndb

If we start a transaction to delete a complex object on appengine and the object has some blob references attached that need to be deleted to, we have a problem. If we just delete the blobs the transaction might fail, but the blobs are gone, because blobstore works independently (this is against the idea of transactions).

Now we have this cool, new NDB wich has an in-context cache without documented API(?) that could solve the problem.

Toolchest:

- ndb.get_context() (undocumented in ndb's function-reference)
- ndb_context.call_on_commit(delete_blobs_call_on_commit)

  ```
  def delete_blobs_call_on_commit():
     ndb_context = ndb.get_context()
     blobstore.delete(ndb_context.list_of_blobkeys_to_delete)
     # OR: taskqueue.add(url+ndb_context.list_of_blobkeys_to_delete)
  ```

Task: Attach blobkeys to delete during the transaction to the context object and delete them after the transaction.

**Update**: call_on_commit() does not allow database operations (that may include blobstore.delete, but have not tried) and will throw a BadRequestError: Cannot start a new operation in a finished transaction, so the only solution might really be the taskqueue.

**Update**: It is possible to call a function with @ndb.non_transactional decorator from a function registered with call_on_commit(). So it is possible to attempt to delete blobs on commit success and hope you have no exceptions which would result in orphans.

Questions: How to safely use the in-context cache? How did you solve the blob deletion problem?

Comment: How will this solve the problem ?  The delete of the blobkey might still fail and now you have orphan blobkeys.  Consider using a roll foward transaction model, that tracks both deletes, run it in a task.  The task can then confirm it has deleted everything, and then clean itself up. If it fails at any point a sweeper can roll foward and retry until all entities are gone.  Just a suggestion.

Comment: I considered pushing all blob deletes into a task queue and deleting the tasks if the transaction fails, but this is inconvenient. delete_blobs_call_on_commit() could still use a taskqueue instead of directly deleting the blobs, but I thought that having a few orphans is acceptable. If blobstore has a success rate of 99.9%, it could be ok. Mainly this question deals with collecting the roll forward data.

Comment: Have you read this article, it might give you some ideas http://blog.notdot.net/2009/9/Distributed-Transactions-on-App-Engine

Comment: If your function to safely delete all blobs needs transaction, it is possible to call it from `call_on_commit` when you decorate it with: `@ndb.transactional(xg=True, propagation=ndb.TransactionOptions.MANDATORY)`. At least, this approach has worked in my experiments so far.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK blobs actually have a representation in the datastore just so you can use them in transactions.

To safely use the in-context cache, use regular Model/Key get() and put() operations with these flags: use_memcache=False, use_datastore=False, use_cache=True.  You can also put those flags in your model definition, as class variables.

Comment: But the __BlobInfo__ objects have no ancestor, and my understanding is no ancestor == no transaction. The main problem to be solved is that deleting a blob during a transaction deletes the blob even if the transaction fails.

Comment: Could you use XP transactions?  Otherwise, you're hosed and you'll have to live with a (very) small probability that you'll be leaking blob keys.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I have more than 5 blobs per group (cross-group (Xg limit is 5).

Comment: Currently I accept the possibility to leak some blobs, but avoid loosing blobs pre transaction commit at all costs, only a taskqueue can solve the leakage problem, as it can retry.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to orphanless deletion of an entity group with blobs could be to have repeatable fault tolerant delete operations without transaction (idempotent operation).

1. Mark the entity/ancestor as deleted, put (important to make sure noone can use it anymore)
2. Delete without transaction from the leaves to the parent
3. Anytime an error occurs, abort
4. The user (sees a deleted item) or the system (taskqueue) can retry the deletion later
5. The delete must be able to skip already deleted references to be idempotent

Can anyone see a problem in that approach?